# Converting a DateTime in 12Hour Format SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, format

I have a scenario in which I have to format time in 12 Hours, if time enters in `PM` part, then I should show Time in 12 Hours Format with `PM`.
below I have achieved the Format but I am unable to find how to extract 12 Hour format with current solution.

```
DECLARE @OpeningTime AS DATETIME
DECLARE @ClosingTime AS DATETIME

SET @OpeningTime = GETDATE()
SET @ClosingTime = '2015-12-29 13:52:36'

SELECT  '<StoreTimings><Section><Days>'
                    + LEFT(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), 3)
                    + '</Days><Timing>'
                    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @OpeningTime, 108)
                    + ( CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,@OpeningTime) > 12
                             THEN ' PM'
                             ELSE ' AM'
                        END ) + '-'
                    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @ClosingTime, 108)
                    + ( CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @ClosingTime) > 12
                             THEN ' PM'
                             ELSE ' AM'
                        END ) + '</Timing></Section></StoreTimings>'
```

The Output is as below

```
<StoreTimings><Section><Days>Tue</Days><Timing>10:31 AM-13:52 PM</Timing></Section></StoreTimings>
```

I need to show `01:52 PM` rather `13:52 PM`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it like this:

```
DECLARE @OpeningTime AS DATETIME
DECLARE @ClosingTime AS DATETIME

SET @OpeningTime = GETDATE()
SET @ClosingTime = '2015-12-29 13:52:36'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, @OpeningTime, 100)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, @ClosingTime, 100)
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6572)**

Also check the [MSDN list for CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187928.aspx) option.

**EDIT:**

To add a space between AM/PM and the time part. You can do

```
select convert(varchar(10), @ClosingTime,120) + RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), @ClosingTime, 22), 11)
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6573)**

**EDIT:**

To get the date in AM/PM format with a space and in HH:MM AM/PM format

```
select convert(varchar(10), @ClosingTime,120) + ' ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(RIGHT('0'+LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),100),7)),7),'AM',' AM'),'PM',' PM')
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6575)**

Comment: can you see. I have a space between `13:52 PM` or `01:52 PM`, this was manually added, I need to add it anyhow.

Comment: @DareDevil:- Updated my answer. Please check!

Comment: @RahulTripathi - i believe your answer is very correct as you are having very less computation and it will be quick complete logic is to prepare an XML string and converting the datetime value in Varchar is also not a concern. +1 for your thought and optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue by following script.

```
DECLARE @OpeningTime AS DATETIME
DECLARE @ClosingTime AS DATETIME

SET @OpeningTime = '2015-12-30 00:30:36'
--GETDATE()
SET @ClosingTime = '2015-12-30 23:59:36'



DECLARE @StoreOpeningTime AS NVARCHAR(8)
DECLARE @StoreClosingTime AS NVARCHAR(8)
DECLARE @Hours AS INT 
SET @Hours = 12

SELECT  @StoreOpeningTime = CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @OpeningTime) >= 12
                             THEN RIGHT('0'
                                        + ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(HOUR,
                                                          @OpeningTime)
                                            - @Hours) ), 2) + ':'
                                  + RIGHT('0'
                                          + ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MINUTE,
                                                          @OpeningTime)) ),
                                          2)
                             ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @OpeningTime, 108)
                        END
    + ( CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @OpeningTime) >= 12 THEN ' PM'
             ELSE ' AM'
        END )


SELECT  @StoreClosingTime = CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @ClosingTime) >= 12
                             THEN RIGHT('0'
                                        + ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(HOUR,
                                                          @ClosingTime)
                                            - @Hours) ), 2) + ':'
                                  + RIGHT('0'
                                          + ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MINUTE,
                                                          @ClosingTime)) ),
                                          2)
                             ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @ClosingTime, 108)
                        END
    + ( CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @ClosingTime) >= 12 THEN ' PM'
             ELSE ' AM'
        END )


SELECT  '<StoreTimings><Section><Days>' + LEFT(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), 3)
    + '</Days><Timing>' + @StoreOpeningTime + '-' + @StoreClosingTime
    + '</Timing></Section></StoreTimings>'
```

Demo at this Link [FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6610/0)